# how to run selenium tests from a dynamic web project which has deployed to tomcat server

Tags: java, servlets, selenium-webdriver, tomcat7, servlet-container

I am trying develop a web application by using jsp,servlet and tomcat server, and from that web application i have to run a selenium test script. but when i am running tat application then it is throwing an error that is Selenium webdriver class could not be loaded although i have set properly all jars and libraries.

Please help me how to run a selenium test from a web application which has deployed to tomcat7 server.. Thanks in advance

This question might have answered but i did not get any proper explanations and solution.Please help me

Comment: If it helps, here is an example I wrote:  https://github.com/djangofan/spring-mvc-testing-example  .  You wont find an example like this on the Spring examples site.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But i need to do with eclipse ide and need to run selenium test classes from the web application.

Comment: Yes, the link I gave above is a Maven project, which also works with Eclipse.  Maven will start Tomcat for you.    You can also run a Tomcat integrated with Eclipse, which is another way to do it, if you don't like how I did it in the link.

Comment: I could build a maven web dynamic project. But i need to call a class(selenium code. Example WebDriver commands)from servlet. While running on the tomcat server .. it is throwing an error that is selenium webdriver class not found although i have set the selenium standalone server in the build path.

Comment: Please help me to figure out this below exception:                              Jan 12, 2016 11:39:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [test.seltest] in context with path [/testp] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1856)

Comment: Your question to hard to answer with limited information.  You would have to share a simple example of all your code, demonstrating the problem  and I cannot guarantee i have time to help.  Maybe I do.  Look closer a the project link I posted above, since during the integration-test phase of the build, when Tomcat starts, if you can get your .war to load and have selenium jars in the webapp.war/lib folder, then it should be able to find classes.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example code that I give below

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", //Driver path as string goes here...);
System.out.println("1");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
System.out.println("2");

capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
System.out.println("3");

try
{
    System.out.println("3.5");
    //create driver
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    System.out.println("4");
```

Import your desired browser exe and related driver in web-inf/res.

Hope it helps.